# How to unpack a packets' wlan layer

Tags: python, sockets, struct, layer, unpack

So I have got the current raw socket:

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, SOCK_STREAM
from struct import unpack
from binascii import hexlify

rawsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW)
rawsocket.bind(("192.168.2.4", 8000))

while True:
    request = rawsocket.recvfrom(2048)

    #this part is for the sake of the question
    if len(request) is not 0:
        print(request)

    request = ""
```

As you see, it waits for an incoming packet on `192.168.2.4` on port `8000`. I can successfully reach this port. I have looked at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html to understand how I must understand the first layer (wlan), but I have no clue whatsoever how to do so.

I have tried googling but no luck, if you know how to unpack this layer, could you also tell me how you know you unpack it like that?

I know I have to do something like this

```
    header = request[0][0:x] #But how for must x go for the wlan layer?
    hd = unpack("y", header) #But what fmt must y be? how do I know?
```

EDIT:

I know that `y` must start with `!`, I also know that `x` has to be the total amount of bytes of that layer: (am I heading in the right direction)

[image]

Comment: based on http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/wireless_lan/wlan_packets it looks like you need to keep reading until you get the terminal character(not sure what that is but it comes right after the checksum) .. you cannot count on a fixed number of bytes for the message ... but you can see that  it has a 2byte FC , a 2byte duration, several 6 byte addresses and some sequence controls ... you will probably have to just do trial and error...

Comment: What mode is your wireless network card in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
header = request[0][0:14]
hd = unpack("!6s6s2s", header)

dest_addr = hexlify(hd[0])
source_addr = hexlify(hd[1])
type = hexlify(hd[2])

print "destination: {0}".format(dest_addr)
print "source: {0}".format(source_addr)
print "destination: {0}".format(type)
```

hd should be a 3 element list of the [Dest Addr, Source Addr, Type/Opcode]

Comment: Yes I tried that already, found it on an other post, but when I try to decode it with `hd = hd[2].decode('UTF-8')` for example, it gives me an invalid start byte error.

Comment: Also, I think `14` should be `30` and `"!6s6s2s"` should be `"!2s2s6s6s6s2s6s"` looking at the above picture.

Comment: Wait what data are you trying to extract from the packet? Also the mode you have your wifi card in is important as it will determine what layer you are sniffing packets on. You're not in monitor mode are you?

Comment: I'm trying to extract all the data of the first layer. `iph`?

Comment: I am 90% sure the packets you are receiving over that raw socket are not 802.11 packets. I understand you are using a wifi card, however by the time the packets get to you, I believe they are Ethernet packets, not WLAN packets. Thus I would focus on looking at the ethernet packet format.

I have updated my comment with a way to print the packets. Does this yield better results?

Comment: I think you are right. When I ran your code it printed out bytes however? (btw i'm running python3)

Comment: try using the ``binascii.b2a_uu(data)`` function to convert the binary data into ascii.

``dest_addr = binascii.b2a_uu(hd[0])``
That should print out something even more friendly.